# How to make a gradle task depends on the "generateOpenApiDocs" task from the springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin (using Kotlin DSL)?

Tags: gradle, swagger-codegen, springdoc

I'm quite new to gradle, and I would like to automate the following tasks :

- Generate an openapi.json file from a SpringBoot application (using the [springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin/))
- Then use this generated file to create a client SDK (using the [Gradle Swagger Generator Plugin](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin#code-generation))

My build.gradle.kts is looking like that:

```
plugin{
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.4"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.14.RELEASE"

  //springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin
  id("org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin") version "1.4.0"

  //https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin
  id("org.hidetake.swagger.generator") version "2.19.2"

  ...
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
  swaggerCodegen("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli:3.3.4")
  ...
}

swaggerSources {
   register("petstore") {
     setInputFile(file("${buildDir}/openapi.json"))
     code.language = "typescript-fetch"
   }
}

// ---!!! the following makes my gradle script fail !!!---
tasks.named("generateSwaggerCodePetstore"){
  dependsOn(tasks.generateOpenApiDocs)
}
```

My problem is that when I would like to run any gradle task, I get as output:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Build file '[...]/build.gradle.kts' line: 153
> - What went wrong:
>   Task with name 'generateOpenApiDocs' not found in root project 'getmad'.

If I remove the following code from my build script ...

```
tasks.named("generateSwaggerCodePetstore"){
  dependsOn(tasks.generateOpenApiDocs)
}
```

... I can easily run these commands:
`$ ./gradlew clean generateOpenApiDocs`
And then:
`$ ./gradlew generateSwaggerCode`
But somehow I'm not able to chain these commands neither to write a programatic dependency between theses tasks in my build script.
I'm having a single gradle Project (no subproject yet).

Has anyone a solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The task `generateOpenApiDocs` is not configured yet so you can't just access it through `tasks`' properties. You have to access it in other way:

```gradle
tasks.named("generateSwaggerCodePetstore") {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("generateOpenApiDocs"))
}
```

The order will be like:

```bash
$ ./gradlew generateSwaggerCodePetstore --dry-run
:app:compileJava SKIPPED
:app:processResources SKIPPED
:app:classes SKIPPED
:app:bootRunMainClassName SKIPPED
:app:forkedSpringBootRun SKIPPED
:app:generateOpenApiDocs SKIPPED
:app:forkedSpringBootStop SKIPPED
:app:generateSwaggerCodePetstore SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it did not work. I still get the same error as before. This is weird because if I add the following task to my script:
`tasks.register("printKnownTasks"){
  println("All known tasks at configuration time:")
  println(rootProject.getAllTasks(true))}`
The tasks is printed:
./gw pKT                                                                                                                                                
All known tasks at configuration time:
{root project 'getmad'=[task ':assemble',[...], task ':generateEffectiveLombokConfig', [...]

Comment: Do u find the solution ? Got the same problem